# Some images not appearing after switching from AWS S3 back to local

Tags: uploads, urls

I'm using a plugin [Amazon AWS for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/aws-for-wp/).

It creates **a copy** of your images on S3 and also serves them from there while active.

When you deactivate it, it should just work locally.

AWS S3 is experiencing problems today so I turned off the plugin and to my surprise there are lot's of missing images.

What could be causing images to not be saved locally but work fine on S3?

*I'm also using a simple filenames plugin to make sure there are no special characters (some people are using Chinese, Cyrillic, etc.) that my local linux machine won't like.*

Here's a page with lots of missing images: http://www.illozoo.com/portfolio/lisk-feng/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is some of your images are redirected. When I inspect one of the missing images in Chrome, right-click on the background-image CSS and open it in a new tab, it is redirecting to the homepage. [HTTP Header Check](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) returns a 302 found, so somewhere these images are still set to redirect. Perhaps you have a caching plugin or a redirect plugin? I'd try deactivating all plugins and then turning them on one by one to identify what may be redirecting. You could also check .htaccess.

Comment: The redirect is happening on 404. If the image is missing it goes to the homepage. (it's on purpose) My problem is that the image is not there at all. When I go to /wp-content/uploads/2014/09/illozoo_dw2sssss.jpg (trough FTP) I don't see it. It is visible on s3 however.

Comment: Gotcha. It looks like no one is providing support for the plugin anymore or I'd say the plugin authors would be the ones to ask. In this case - I'd start by going to the Media Library to see if WP has placeholders for these missing images. If there are no placeholders then somehow the images didn't get saved to the database - that would be a problem with the plugin and you'll need to reupload through the Media Library rather than FTP. If there are placeholders it's safe to download from AWS and upload via FTP to the right folders.

Comment: Since the plugin hasn't been supported in awhile you may not find a good answer as to why this issue occurred - you may want to try to find a newer plugin to replace it.